`Import error cannot import name triu from scipy linalg gensim` can I just change the source code?
So there is an import error with the latest version of gensim and there's traffic around the question.  I noticed that triu is now part of numpy, so it's trivially easy to fix this problem without a downgrade.  Is that a bad practice?
In <python-install>/site-packages/gensim/matutils.py (or your equivalent path to the gensim install), line 21 imports triu from scipy.linalg.  I literally removed this import and added one line such that the imports now look like:
from numpy import triu
from scipy.linalg import get_blas_funcs

And everything works fine for me.  Any reason not to use this?  Since I don't have enough rep to actually answer other similar questions, you guys can throw rocks and tell me why that's bad.  Thanks!
I changed the source code as explained above and now the package works fine for me!  Maybe it's bad practice though.

This change is pretty much what the official patch to gensim does. (The official patch has a fallback to scipy.linalg.triu if np.triu is missing, but this isn't needed, for the reasons I explain here.)
